# Manual indentation setting in Monodevelop 4.0.12

Tags: c, monodevelop, indentation

I'm working with C in Monodevelop 4.0.12.
When I write statements like loops or if-statements, I usually indent my code in the curly braces. MD places the cursor in the same column of `for`. Can I change an option to place it always indented?
P.S:Sorry if my english is not perfect, it's not my main language.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you type the left curly brace?

Comment: same line of the loop description

Comment: Does it do that when you edit a new file or for any C file (with en extension `.c` or `.h` ?

Comment: No it is always in the same column